# IPhone: NSHTTPCookie wont set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cookies

I do this, but the new cookie doesn't show up, just some other cookies that are already set. What's wrong?

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:[NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                             @"www.mydomain.com", NSHTTPCookieOriginURL,
                                                                                             @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                                                                             @"mycookiename", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                                                                             @"mycookievalue", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                                                                             nil]]];
 NSLog(@"%@",[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting an `NSURL` into the [`NSHTTPCookieOriginURL`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSHTTPCookieOriginURL) property?

```
NSURL *originURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com"];
```

It looks like you can use an `NSString` or an `NSURL`, but either way the URL you specify must conform to the [standards](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/definitions/url.html) outlined in RFC 2396 (e.g. "http://x.y.z", etc.).

Also make sure you're not overlooking [any other required cookie properties or formatting of those properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001702-425346).

Comment: NSURL did the job! Thanks!
Note that NSLog(@"%@",[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]) will trow an exception in this case (don't know why) but NSLog(@"%@",[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) will work.